# Django `TransactionTestCase` test cases with AWS RDS are very slow

Tags: django, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I am trying to set up Django tests to use AWS RDS as a Postgres database backnend (tests are executed on Heroku CI which does not allow you create and destroy test databases). The tests are running, but test cases that use `TransactionTestCase` are extremely slow (sometimes up to a minute compared to a fraction of a second when not using RDS). I am using RDS in the same region as my Heroku deployment (EU/Ireland) and test cases based on `TestCase` class run as usual.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

`TransactionTestCase` is very slow compared to `TestCase`.  I have started inheriting from `TestCase` and then putting each block of celery and db calls inside a `transaction.atomic():` block, and doing my queries and asserts outside that block.  You get the speed of a `TestCase`.

Example:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    Foo.objects.create(...)
    Bar.objects.get_or_create(...)
self.assertEqual(Foo.objects.count(), 1)
self.assertTrue(Bar.objects.first().trueproperty)
```